# Gateway between Power BI and Excel

Tags: powerbi

Good afternoon,

I want to do an automatic update between Power BI and an Excel that I have on my desktop of my laptop.
I already installed the Gateway, here is the configuration of the origin of the information.
[image]

Could you tell me how these fields are completed to make a correct connection

Answer (score 0):

Use the same path that you have used in the Power Query Source for the workbook.

Use credentials that can access that file.

If you have several workbooks in different places, you need connections for each workbook.

Comment: in my case I only have an excel file on my desktop named data.xlsx. I have not used the power query, only the power bi. So my query on how to complete those fields in the photo I uploaded

Comment: If you load the file into Power BI, you ARE using Power Query. Use the same path.